# Jane's investment options: I can't get the logs to work...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I set this age-15 question to be done in Excel, which is easy enough.

When I tried to solve it - to confirm the answer - I got stuck:

Jane has two investment options:

i) $\$5000 @ 5\%$ pa compound interest, with no setup fee, and

ii) $\$5000 @ 8\%$ pa compound interest, with an up-front $2000 setup fee.

When would the two investments be equal in value?

I started with

$5000(1.08)^t - 2000 = 5000(1.05)^t$

which led to

$5000(1.08^t - 1.05^t) = 2000$

then

$1.08^t - 1.05^t = 0.4$

How do I 'take logs' to solve for t?

Comment: The second option was auto-formatted incorrectly (three times!). It should be five thousand dollars invested at 8 percent compound interest per annum plus a two thousand dollar up-front setup fee. Sorry about that.

Comment: There does not seem to be any way to solve that equation using the standard, elementary functions, but there are many ways to get approximate answers. High school classes give the impression that algebra can solve all equations, but that is not true. For example, Abel/Ruffini proved that the equation $x^5-x+1=0$ cannot be solved by the usual algebra techniques. Adding "logs" still leaves many equations unsolvable with exact answers.

Comment: I would think that $$2000= 5000[\bigg(\frac{1.08}{1.05}\bigg)^t-1]$$

Comment: Thank you for the editing and formatting help, much appreciated.